Create PostGIS column of a specific H3 hexID/resolution
I've used H3 in the past just for speeding up my spatial queries, however I'm looking for the best way to store the index information itself alongside my data.
Something like: CREATE COLUMN H3res14 --> populate with: 'h3.geo_to_h3(data.lat, data.lng, resolution14)'
Essentially I'm trying to find the quickest way to build the following into my tables:
|__FID__| |__Col1__|... |__H3Res15__| |__H3Res10__| |__H3Res05__| ...etc

    1       river          hexID         hexID         hexID
    2       river          hexID         hexID         hexID
   ...       ...            ...           ...           ...

Its essentially binning vector data into H3 hex at a specific resolution, but then storing the result in the table itself as a column. Seems something I can do manually but I wanted to see if I'm missing something obvious (eg. something built into PostGIS/H3) that does it more efficiently.

As commented by @geozelot:

Create columns -> Populate columns - that's the deal. This blog
uses GENERATED columns to do that, try it. Note that this is not a
spatial index in the stricter sense, rather a 1 dimensional R-Tree
value index on a string column, being performant for simple equality
checks. Distance is only approximate and lossy.

